# C++ Does an abstract class without any data fields need a constructor?

Tags: c++

Does an abstract class without any data fields need a constructor?

Also, since the implementation of the `makeAMove` function is in the derived classes, is it necessary to create a separate implementation file for this `Player` class or is a this single .h file alright?

```
#pragma once // include guard
#include "Board.h"

class Player
{
    public:
        virtual void makeAMove(Board &myBoard) = 0; // pure virtual function
};
```

Comment: Don't ask two separate questions in the same post.  Make a new post, the question for this one has already been answered.

Comment: Okay. Sorry about that.

Comment: The question now only contains the original question.

Answer (score 3):

*Every* class has a constructor, probably more than one. However, you don't always need to *declare* or *define* a constructor yourself, since under favourable conditions this happens implicitly. Such is the case in your example.

You also don't need an implementation file, since that would not contain anything.

Comment: The destructor would also be created implicitly as well, right?

Comment: @navig8tr: sure, and assignment operators, too.

Comment: He could theotetically implement the pure virtual functions too, if he felt the need for a default implementation that he could explicitly. Beyond the scope of this I suppose, but possible :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the purpose of the abstract class is to provide polymorphic functionality through virtual funcions, that is, the class is an interface.

The base class should have a virtual dtor to ensure the correct destruction of polymorphic instances.

A good rule is: Every time a class hierarchy is dessigned to provide polymorphic functionality through dynamic binding, its base class should have a virtual dtor.

About classes and headers, C++ does not restrict you to write one class per file (as Java does).

What is more correct, to write one class per file or more than one classes? Depends, I think this is subjective. But in general C and C++ uses headers to provide functionality, and functionality commonly implies more than one class.